# JavaScript Countdown not working (showing NaN) in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

This timer countdown works fine in Chrome, but doesn't work in Firefox...it just shows up as NaN. Anyone know why this is happening?

```js
var deadline = 'May 3 2017 08:30:00 CST-0500';
function time_remaining(endtime){
 var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
 var seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
 var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
 var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
 var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
 return {'total':t, 'days':days, 'hours':hours, 'minutes':minutes, 'seconds':seconds};
}
function run_clock(id,endtime){
 var clock = document.getElementById(id);
 
 // get spans where our clock numbers are held
 var days_span = clock.querySelector('.days');
 var hours_span = clock.querySelector('.hours');
 var minutes_span = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
 var seconds_span = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

 function update_clock(){
  var t = time_remaining(endtime);
  
  // update the numbers in each part of the clock
  days_span.innerHTML = t.days;
  hours_span.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
  minutes_span.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
  seconds_span.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);
  
  if(t.total<=0){ clearInterval(timeinterval); }
 }
 update_clock();
 var timeinterval = setInterval(update_clock,1000);
}
run_clock('clockdiv',deadline);
```

Comment: HTML code as well please!

Comment: Please update your snippet with HTML to create a [mcve]

Comment: _“Anyone know why this is happening?”_ – because you are trying to create a Date object from a format that Firefox does not support.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. Working now, thanks!